# Is there any short and best method to load set of required javascript at one stretch and other Javascript files after page load?

Tags: javascript, web, scripting, progressive-web-apps, pageload

Requirement:

- Load scripts required for page load initially (means scripts download should start at same point)
- other third party scripts should be loaded once the page dom loaded.(these scripts also should start the download at same point)

We tried:
 - Loaded req scripts before body
 - Added listener to load the second set of scripts after page dom load

But still script downloads starts not so proper.
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you mean irregular? Are there not loading on time? Is your code not able to execute on your page? I don't know what you are asking exactly but maybe you are looking for something like bundling?

Comment: Now in desc, please check two images, where first image is how i want to load my scripts, and the second is how the scripts are loading after implementation.

Comment: Sorry I can't see images. Not your fault, just my firewall :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Window load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event to know when your page finished loading(excluding 3rd party scripts which is not primary need for your page), and [load any other 3rd party scripts](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)/manipulations/rendering/what ever inside the event handler.

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("All resources finished loading!");

   $.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
     .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
     })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
       $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
    });

  });
</script>
```

Also use bundling tools like webpack to bundle all your primary JS files into one file, CSS into one file. That will increase your page load significantly.